# Will [NSSet allObjects] return an array with the same order each time?

Tags: iphone, core-data, uitableview, nsset

I have a list of custom objects being returned from a .NET WebService and am storing them using a To-Many relationship from the parent enitity with Core Data.

I want to use the NSSet as the datasource for a UITableView and push a new controller onto the stack when a row is selected.

When using `[NSSet allObjects]` does the array returned always have the same order? (I guess not as sets are unordered)

If not, how then can I use `NSArray *myArray = [mySet allObjects];` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to get the name for the `textLabel` of the cell and then again in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to assign the object to the ViewController about to be pushed?

I already have the parent object synthesized in my `UITableViewDelegate`. I have thought about also having an `NSArray` synthesized and using `allObjects` only once in `viewDidLoad` to create but this is duplicating the data in memory

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your solution, extracting an `NSArray` once during `viewDidLoad`, is the correct one. You actually won't be duplicating much memory. Your objects will still only be in memory once; it's just that your `NSSet` and `NSArray` will both contain pointers to those objects.

Answer (score 33):

There's no guarantee that they'll be in the same order, since an `NSSet` does not (technically) maintain order.  If it so happens that the objects *do* come back in the same order each time, then be aware that that's an implementation detail, is not documented, and could potentially be changed in a future release of the frameworks.

To quote [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000143-CHDDFHBE):

> (`-[NSSet allObjects]` returns) [a]n array containing the set’s members, or an empty array if the set has no members. **The order of the objects in the array isn’t defined.**

(emphasis added)

Comment: This answer actually has the answer to the original question.

Answer (score 3):

Use NSOrderedSet instead of NSSet.